# Parsing line of text into different variables using php

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am very new to php so I apologize for the seemingly simple question. I need to parse a line of text into different variables. More specifically, I need to parse many lines of text in different arrays. The line of text would resemble the following

```
timeStamp UserName* garbage text Number x item*
timeStamp UserName* garbage text Number x item*
timeStamp UserName* garbage text Number x item*
```

both userName and item could contain spaces. I would assume the best way to go about this would be 4 different arrays?

actual data would look like the following

```
03:12:34 mhopkins321 has acquired 5 x bottles of water
09:38:01 Nick Smith has acquired 100 x pennies
23:22:59 Fancy Frank has acquired 15684 x artichoke hearts
```

So I would assume the arrays would be

```
$timeStamp         $userName        $amount     $items
03:12:34           mhopkins321      5           bottles of water
09:38:01           Nick Smith       100         pennies
23:22:59           Fancy Frank      15684       artichoke hearts
```

Comment: http://php.net/explode? http://php.net/preg_match?

Comment: From a file ??? Does your garbage text contain spaces ??

Comment: Show some actual lines and what do you want to have in array

Comment: The sscanf() function might be useful, but without knowing the actual details it's not so easy to confirm a best answer

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @piotrekkr I've added actual data.

Comment: @JackManey I've played around with parse_str however I'm not entirely sure that is designed for what I'm using. I've worked with parsing csv's using powershell quite frequently, however with no clear delimiter I'm confused the best way to go about it. My plan is to take this data and use the googleAPI to add it into a spreadsheet. So I am also unclear as to the best way to do that, whether it be a loop with no array, or using an array

Comment: If your lines always follow the same format, I'd suggest a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad format for machine parsing. Especially problematic is that names may have spaces but are not delimited.

The only foolproof way to parse this is to know all the "garbage text" strings that may appear between the name and the amount. Unless you have a complete list, you may mess up your user names.

It's possible to parse this using `explode()` to split a line into an array and then extracting parts. However, I think you should just use a regular expression.

```
$sample = "
03:12:34 mhopkins321 has acquired 5 x bottles of water
09:38:01 Nick Smith has acquired 100 x pennies
23:22:59 Fancy Frank has acquired 15684 x artichoke hearts
";

$re = '/^(?<timeStamp>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) # timestamp 
         \s+
         (?<userName>[\w\s]+)        # user name
         \s+(?:has\s+acquired)\s+    # garbage text between name and amount
         (?<amount>\d+)              # amount
         \s+x\s+                     # multiplication symbol
         (?<items>.*)\s*$            # item name (to end of line)
       /xmu';

preg_match_all($re, $sample, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_export($matches);
```

Comment: The lack of defined deliminators was my issue with this as well. The "garbage text" will always be " has acquired " which I suppose is helpful to some extent

Comment: It's not "helpful to some extent", it's absolutely essential information.

Comment: Doing this makes me love csvs that much more

Comment: When I execute this all that is returned is `array ( )` I have tried `echo $matches`, `echo $matches[0]`, `var_export($matches)` and any combination I can think of yet I get nothing. Any thoughts of avenues I can pursue?

Comment: The code I have written above works for me. Maybe you have an older version of PHP that doesn't support named capturing (the `(?<name>pattern)` stuff)? Does `preg_match_all` return `0` (no match) or `FALSE` (something wrong with the pattern or input). And turn error logging on and check your logs.

Comment: according to my webhost I'm using 5.3

Comment: quick question regarding the regular expression you provided above. i edited the above question to show how some of the data is being passed in. particular 'item'. It seems to include a carriage return, when in fact that is no bueno. Any idea how I might be able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you going need a regular expression to split the text line.
It is not so easy to understand but a tool you need for other cases like this you related.
Manual page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

You need find patterns on the text.
For example the timestamp always start at very begin of line and ahs 8 characters in length?

Comment: correct. time stamp is always 8 characters. item is always after the "x" however it is possible for there to be more than one x in the string. number is always before the x. and username can exist between timestamp and number, and possibly trim out " has acquired " each time?

Comment: ok but the end of string should always match a product and you know there is a constant string has acquired. Francis regex is pretty complete to resolve your case.